# radio buttons for XML document

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a xml document that contains a question and 4 answers. I can get it to appear but want each of the answers to appear with a radio button, I am using Javascript to get the XML document to appear, can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You just need to generate a suitable `<input>` element when you transform the XML into HTML (I'm assuming you are creating an HTML document since you are using JS and that is the most common use case).